# Куда сохраняется значение введенное в input

Tags: php, apache, form

Допустим я отправил форму из `form.php` на `form.php`
методом POST и вывел массив `print_r($_POST);`

```html
<form action="form.php" method="POST">
        <input type="text" name="email" value="">
        <input type="submit" name="">
</form>
```

Затем на сайте в `input` ввел текст `ktoto@mai.com`
и нажал на `submit`
после чего `print_r($_POST);`  вывел на сайте `Array ( [email] => ktoto@mai.com )`
Вопрос в том куда сохранился `[email] => ktoto@mai.com`?
Это `куки` или `сессии`, или что ?

Comment: в атрибуте html-формы указан метод передачи данных  **POST** - при таком методе на сервере будет создан суперглобальный массив $_POST, ключи которого будут содержать имена, которые соответствуют атрибутам name из текстовых полей, а  значения будут соответствовать значениям текст.полей.

Comment: то есть `$_POST ` создает `интерпретатор` работающий на `apache`  и прикрепил его к файлу `form.php` ?

Comment: да, именно так.

Comment: а как он прикрепляет его к файлу ?

Comment: он не крепит его к файлу - сервер возвращает результат обратно клиенту _(браузеру)_ по тому же каналу, по которому он получал запрос _(HTTP)_ , ну а браузер распечатывает этот результат на монитор.

Comment: я решил запостить свой камент.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если в атрибуте html-формы будет указан метод передачи данных **POST** - то на сервере будет создан суперглобальный массив **$_POST**, ключами которого будут имена, которые в свою очередь соответствуют атрибутам **name** из текстовых полей *(`<input>`, `<textarea>` и т.п.)*, а значениями этих ключей будут значения, которые были введены в текст.поля, или которые записаны по умолчанию в атрибут **value="Какой-то текст по умолчанию"**.

> *куда сохранился [email] => ktoto@mai.com*

Строго говоря, значения в суперглобальном массиве $_POST никуда не сохраняются, и при последующем обновлении страницы методом $_GET они *(эти значения)* будут сброшены. Для хранения этих значений можно использовать текстовые файлы, или базы данных, или *(если данных не много, и хранить надо не долго)* сессии, или куки. Выбор хранилища основывается на конкретной реализации той или иной задачи.

Answer (score 0):

> куда сохранился `[email] => ktoto@mai.com`

Значение `input` пришло на сервер POST запросом и Вы его тут же, по сути,  вернули обратно, выведя массив данных запроса на страницу через `print_r`.

Тип запроса указан в атрибуте `method` тега `form`. А, для того чтобы получить доступ к параметрам POST запроса в PHP существует [специальный массив](http://php.net/manual/ru/reserved.variables.post.php) `$_POST`, где имена элементов соответствуют именам полей формы.

Как-то так...